# QT C++ Создание ISO-образа

Tags: c++, qt, iso-образ

Появилась задача создать простую программу для создания ISO-образов с компакт-диска на C++. Однако, в дебрях интернета несколько запутался и не смог найти какой-то вменяемый пример или библиотеку.

Находил информацию, что использовать надо:

- IMAPI2 Windows API для работы с дисками
- libcdio

Но примеров создания образов или вменяемого описания так и не нашел.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: в сторону IMAPI2, посмотрите тут примеры кода https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22538/Burning-CD-DVD-Media-with-the-Image-Mastering-API https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23653/How-to-Create-Optical-File-Images-using-IMAPIv2-0

Comment: Если линух дергайте dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, примеров нету, потому что задача создания образа ISO фактически сводится к задаче побайтового копирования данных с устройства в файл. Подробнее это обсуждалось здесь: [Склонировать диск (в т.ч системный) в ISO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877005/)

IMAPI тут не нужен, достаточно обычных файловых API. Основная сложность состоит в том, чтобы реализовать чтение с устройства в конкретной ОС.

Реализация под Windows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const unsigned int SECTOR_SIZE = 2048; //размер сектора для CD

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>

void GetDiskMetrics(const char* disk, unsigned int* pBlockSize, uint64_t* pTotalSize){

    char path[MAX_PATH]="";
    strcpy(path,disk);
    strcat(path,":\\"); 

    unsigned long  dwSectorsPerCluster, dwBytesPerSector, dwNumberOfFreeClusters, dwTotalNumberOfClusters;
    unsigned int  blocksize;
    uint64_t totalsize;

    //найдем размер сектора и объем данных на диске
    int res = GetDiskFreeSpaceA(path, &dwSectorsPerCluster, &dwBytesPerSector,
                &dwNumberOfFreeClusters, &dwTotalNumberOfClusters);

    //вычислим размер блока, кратный размеру сектора, и общий объем данных в байтах
    if (res){
        blocksize = dwBytesPerSector * 20;
        totalsize = dwSectorsPerCluster * dwBytesPerSector * (uint64_t)dwTotalNumberOfClusters;
    }
    else{
        printf("GetDiskFreeSpace error %d", GetLastError());
        blocksize = SECTOR_SIZE * 20;
        totalsize = 4700307456; //DVD
    }

    *pBlockSize = blocksize;
    *pTotalSize = totalsize;
}

bool OpenDevice(const char* disk, void** phFile){
    char path[MAX_PATH]=""; 
    sprintf(path,"\\\\.\\%s:",disk); //формат имени файла для открытия тома

    //открываем том для прямого доступа на чтение
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileA(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fprintf(stderr,"CreateFileA error %d", GetLastError());  
        return false;
    }
    else {
        *phFile = handle;
        return true;
    }
}

bool ReadDevice(void* hFile, void* lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead){

    BOOL res = ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, NULL);

    if (res == FALSE){
        fprintf(stderr,"ReadFile error %d", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

void CloseDevice(void* hFile){
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
#endif

void CreateISO(const char* disk, const char* outfile){      

    char* buf;
    unsigned long dwRead = 0;
    uint64_t count = 0;     
    unsigned int  blocksize;
    uint64_t totalsize; 

    GetDiskMetrics(disk,&blocksize,&totalsize);
    buf = (char*)malloc(blocksize);     

    //открываем том для прямого доступа на чтение    
    void* handle=NULL;
    bool res = OpenDevice(disk,&handle);
    if (res == false)  goto End;    

    //открываем файл для записи
    FILE* target = fopen(outfile,"wb");

    while (true){
        dwRead = 0;
        memset(buf,0,blocksize);

        //считаем блок данных
        res = ReadDevice(handle,buf, blocksize, &dwRead);
        if (res == false) goto End;

        if (dwRead == 0) break; //конец считывания

        count += dwRead;

        printf(" Creating image: %5.1f%% [%10.2f KB / %10.2f KB]\r",
               (count * 100.0f / totalsize),
               (count / 1024.0f),
               (totalsize / 1024.0f));

        //запишем блок в файл
        fwrite(buf,dwRead,1,target);                    
     }

     End: CloseDevice(handle);
          fclose(target);
          free(buf);
          printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    CreateISO("K", "c:\\distr\\image.iso");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Чтобы заставить это работать под другими ОС, вам нужно будет реализовать функции, расположенные в блоке `#ifdef _WIN32`.

Comment: Другие программы работы с ISO - образами смогут открыть такой файл?

Comment: @Larboss Да.....